# What does _sonata_admin: {resource: . } do in routing.yml?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

When setting up SonataAdmin, you have to add an entry like this one:

```
_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin
```

In this entry, what does `resource: .` do? It's somewhat unusual syntax and I'd like to add a footnote about it to the SonataAdmin docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The routing component needs a `resource` attribute (at least with sf2.0). The `AdminPoolLoader` class is in charge on loading the route and the `support` method only check the `type` attribute and not the resource name provided ....

So the dot is just a value that others `RoutingLoader` cannot validate and generate errors...

Comment: OK, so ``resource: .`` is needed to pass validation, but it's not actually used by AdminPoolLoader?

Comment: You must have typed that edit at the same time as me. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: But what does the second line do (_sonata_admin)? I tried commenting it, and everything seems to work just fine. Is it some backwards compatibility thing?

Comment: @burgeris this is required for the AdminPoolLoader, see: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/master/Route/AdminPoolLoader.php#L51-L58